# vector of string in c#

Tags: c#, c++

I'm here to ask you help with a code i'm working on.

I'm converting a tool from C++ to C#.

I've almost completed everything, but...

There's the code in C++ of Struct and how the tool use it:

```
struct Line
{
    uint16_t Magic;
    std::vector<std::string> Params;
}
```

This is the structure, the tool use like this in a switch:

```
case MAGIC_FUNCTION_BEGIN:
{
    pLine -> Params[0][8] = ' ';
    Output << pLine -> Params[0];
    pLine -> Params.erase(pLine->Params.begin());
    Output << GenParams(pLine->Params) << '\n';
    break;
}
```

So, now, the question is:

How is possible that use pLine -> Params[0][8] if it is a simple string vector?

Thanks!

---

Thank you so much for the answer.

I resolved in C# by setting it as:

```
char[] text = pLine.param[0].ToCharArray();
text[8] = ' ';
pLine.param[0] = text.ToString();
```

Now i've to ask something else about this code...

What it means when it does

```
pLine -> Params.erase(pLine->Params.begin());
```

How can be converted to C# something like erase and begin?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of expression `Params[0]` is reference to an object of type std::string. Shortly speaking `Params[0]` is an object of type `std::string` and applying the second subscript operator `Params[0][8]` you will get the character at position 8.

That it would be more clear you could split statement

```
pLine -> Params[0][8] = ' ';
```

into two statements

```
std::string &s = pLine -> Params[0];
s[8] = ' ';
```

In fact you have two containers where one container is put in another container.

Answer (score 1):

`std::string` has an [`operator[]`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator%5B%5D/) for accessing the individual elements.

`pLine->Params[0][8]` means "access the 9th character of the first parameter in `pLine`". In this case, it's set to a space character ''.